# Adding an element to the beginning of jQuery set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery object, that contains a set of elements. When i want to push an element to the end of the set, all is nice and well, everything works fine.
But i cannot found a way to insert an element to the beginning of the set, because an order is important to me and there is not `.unshift()` equivalent in jQuery. Code example follows:

```
   var imgs = $slider.find(".scroll-container");
   var element = $("#someElement");
   imgs.push(element)     //works, element is the last element of the imgs set
   imgs.???(element)   //to put element to the beginning of the set
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: do you want to insert the elements into the DOM or you simply want to add them to an array?

Comment: Actually - both. I'm making jsfiddle right now to show what i mean.

Comment: jsFiddle proves to be too long, as i use jade + coffeescript in my project, but i think i got my answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not go the other way around like this:

```
element.push(imgs);
imgs = element;
```

Tough i would use the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method instead of push.

---

Based on Stephen Byrne answer i have an ideea

```
$.fn.unshift = [].unshift;
imgs.unshift(element);
```

Comment: Not exactly what i need. It's a block slider + scroll, which uses imgs array to find out what elements are hidden and shown and if i reach end of this array i use ajax to get more blocks into slider, and then either append or prepend them; so i can't start by reversing it.

Comment: And you still get the vote, as you led me to correct answer. You only need not to push imgs into element but use `imgs.each ->` and push one by one.

Comment: Ok, glad it helped. But if it's not exactly what you need, please update your question and add the answer, future fellow programmers might learn from it :)

Comment: Elegant solution all the same!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) methods instead:

```
imgs.append(element);
imgs.prepend(element);
```

Comment: prepends or appends element to EACH element in the set.

Comment: @АндрейПочекуев Correct, have you tried this? If you will have only one `.scroll-container` collection it will prepend only once. What's the problem?

Comment: I think he wants to add an image to the collection, not add an image to each of the images in the collection.

Comment: @Nunners he will NOT add image to EACH image using prepend, he will add only one image to collection. Look closer into the code: he use `.find(".scroll-container")` this will be just parent node of images, and then using prepend and append he will add just 2 images: to the beginning and to the end of collection.

Comment: @antyrat `insert content in dom` is not the same as `insert content in a set` don't you think ?

Comment: `.scroll-container` is not a single element.

Comment: @PoelincaDorin k, will wait what will be his reponse to `skip405` comment as it's not clear for me...

Comment: @АндрейПочекуев and what it is then? Can you show us some HTML or jsFiddle demo?

Comment: If he uses the push() method, that doesn't add content in the dom like prepend and append, am i right ? So based on that we know what he needs!

Comment: @PoelincaDorin but jQuery API doesn't have `push()` method either. This is Array method and `imgs` is jQuery collection.

Comment: Exactly my point, he wants the content added to a `set` witch is basically a collection/array/...

Answer (score 1):

toungue *very firmly in my cheek* with this answer:

```
$.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
//get, reverse
var imgs = $slider.find(".scroll-container").reverse();
//add to end
imgs.push(element);
//reverse again
imgs = imgs.reverse();
```

Obviously it's not very efficient although that being said any array insertion other than append to end is going to be inefficient :)